# SSRS Report Builder - Show colums with zero value on bar chart

Tags: sql, reporting-services, charts, zero, reportbuilder

I've created a one week forecast graph that predicts the amount of packages we will receive over the next week. The dataset query is grabbing the columns for each day and then report builder is doing a count of associated tracking numbers. My issue is that it skips columns with a count value of 0 packages expected.  So for example, it goes from Today to +2 days, skipping Tomorrow if count(tomorrow)=0. I would like the report to display all columns regardless of a 0 count. Any ideas?

Select query for reference -

```
SELECT 
    TrackingNumber,
    case when DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),ScheduledDelivery)=0 then' Today'
         when DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),ScheduledDelivery)=1 then' Tomorrow'
         when DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),ScheduledDelivery)=2 then'+2 Days'
         when DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),ScheduledDelivery)=3 then'+3 Days'
         when DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),ScheduledDelivery)=4 then'+4 Days'
         when DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),ScheduledDelivery)=5 then'+5 Days'
         when DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),ScheduledDelivery)=6 then'+6 Days'
        else NULL
        end as 'Delivery Day'
```

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your dataset looks like when it's complete it's difficult to give an exact answer but let's assume it looks something like

| TrackNo | DeliveryDate | ANumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | Today | 5 |
| ABC123 | +2 Days | 3 |
| ABC123 | +3 Days | 7 |
| ABC123 | +4 Days | 8 |
| ABC123 | +6 Days | 9 |

and yo want it to look like this...

| TrackNo | DeliveryDate | ANumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | Today | 5 |
| ABC123 | Tomorrow | 0 |
| ABC123 | +2 Days | 3 |
| ABC123 | +3 Days | 7 |
| ABC123 | +4 Days | 8 |
| ABC123 | +5 Days | 0 |
| ABC123 | +6 Days | 9 |

Then you could just create a table (or table variable) containing all possible values and left join to this. You can also simplify the query doing this too as you will no longer need the case statement

Something like

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(DelDays int, DelCaption varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(0, 'Today'),
(1, 'Tomorrow'),
(2, '+2 Days'),
(3, '+3 Days'),
(4, '+4 Days'),
(5, '+5 Days'),
(6, '+6 Days')

SELECT 
        a.TrackNo, t.DelCaption, ISNULL(a.ANumber,0) AS ANumber
    FROM @t t
    LEFT JOIN myTable a 
        ON t.DelDays = DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),ScheduledDelivery)
```

If you do this a lot then I suggest you create a new table to permanently hold the data we've put into `@t` in the example above.